# Parsing XML data using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to parse all data from below XML file. Please guide me how can I do it? How can I put data into a separate variables or array. Like, the value of `<p:productid>` tag into $pid and value of `<p1:devices>` into $pdevice?

Here is a sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <p:application>


      <p1:devices>
         <p1:device>First device</p1:device>
         <p1:device>Second Device</p1:device>
     </p1:devices>    

 </p:versions> 
</p:application>
```

Comment: SimpleXML is a minimalistic XML parsing library for PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for that.

Here is a good tutorial to get you started:

[Introduction To SimpleXML With PHP](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html)

Comment: bro i see those examples..but cannot solved my issue.this xml are discontinious..can u pls write a sample code for me?? thanks for ur ans..

Comment: @riad: Well bro, we are supposed to answer questions, not do-this-for-me anyways. I would strongly recommend you to learn those as you might confront them in the future too :)

Comment: just tell me a single thing how can i parse data between < p3:appAccess > < /p3:appAccess > tag because xml perser can easily parse data from < appAccess > tag but here have an extra vale like p3: so its show ing error..pls help..